# Maven project not running, main class invalid or missing error

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I converted a java project to maven project, it builds and cleans just fine, but when I try to run it using mvn exec:java, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project ExcelPublicationService: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

My pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ExcelPublicationService</groupId>
<artifactId>ExcelPublicationService</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <mainClass>bns.gwt.dpm.service.rest.main.DynamicUdfPublicationServer</mainClass>
                    <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-http-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

The main class is located under:
src\main\java\bns\gwt\dpm\service\rest\main

its called DynamicUdfPublicationServer.java

and has a package name :

```
package bns.gwt.dpm.service.rest.main
```

The source files are in :

```
ExcelPublicationService/src/main/java
```

and maven compiles the classes to :

```
ExcelPublicationService\target\classes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [exec-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) for [exec:java](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) goal . See the plugin usage [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html)

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <mainClass>bns.gwt.dpm.service.rest.main.DynamicUdfPublicationServer</mainClass>
                    <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Note that you do not require `<pluginManagement>... <pluginManagement/>` tags.

or

From command line, you have to execute

`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="bns.gwt.dpm.service.rest.main.DynamicUdfPublicationServer"`